# Derivatives: enter "evaluated at" vertical bar with multiple values as subscripts

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, subscripts, delimiters

Sorry for the long title, but how do I enter evaluated at (for a derivative), with multiple valuation criteria at the bottom of the the big `|` line?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think that both answers should be helpful to you. Just for the next time, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and help you with you problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You mean `\frac{d}{dx}\Bigr|_{\substack{x=1\\y=2}}` from the package `\usepackage{amsmath}` ?

Answer (score 21):

Is this what you mean?  If so, here are three possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\(
 \left. {\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}}%
 \right|_{%
 \stackunder[1pt]{$\scriptscriptstyle t=0$}{$\scriptscriptstyle t=1$}}
\)
~~
\(
 \left. {\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}}%
_{\stackunder[1pt]{}{}}%
 \right|_{%
 \stackon[1pt]{$\scriptscriptstyle t=0$}{$\scriptscriptstyle t=1$}}
\)
~~
\(
 \left. \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right|_{%
\stackon[1pt]{$\scriptscriptstyle t=0$}{$\scriptscriptstyle t=1$}}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for examples! What are the differences in your three examples in terms of the syntax? I can see the differences in the results, but what do the `\stackunder`, `\stackon` and `\scriptscriptstyle` do in these contexts? Also, what does this do that the `\substack` macro (from the `amsmath` package) doesn't do?

Comment: @jvriesem I'm not sure how `\substack` behaves, but having written the `stackengine` package, I know how it behaves.  The `\scriptscriptstyle` merely sets the math in its smallest standard style associated with subscripts of subscripts.  The `\stackon` will lay the first item on the baseline and place the 2nd item above it, whereas the `\stackunder` will lay the first item on the baseline and stack the second item below it.  In these example, the baseline is where a simple single-line subscript would normally end up.  I use a false (empty) stack in example 2 to extend the reach of the `|`.

Comment: @jvriesem  The `stackengine` package also allows its arguments to be processed, by default, in math mode.  Therefore, if you invoke the macro `\stackMath` in the preamble, you can remove all the `$` delimiters in the stacking arguments.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Notation_(details)) seems to use `\left. \frac{dx}{dt} \right|_{text}` as well. I like that it's more semantically meaningful than just using an arbitrary `\Bigr|`.