# "Evaluated at" bar for derivatives: \Bigr, \biggr, or \left...\right?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, delimiters

I'm trying to determine if there is a best practice for typesetting the "evaluated at" bar for derivatives. The three possibilities I'm thinking of are shown in the code excerpt below:

```
\begin{gather*}
5 + \frac{df}{dt} \Bigr\rvert_{t = 0} \\
5 + \frac{df}{dt} \biggr\rvert_{t = 0} \\
5 + \left. \frac{df}{dt} \right\rvert_{t = 0} \\
\end{gather*}
```

[image]

The `\Bigr` option doesn't quite reach the top and bottom of the fraction. The `\biggr` option overshoots the top and bottom of the fraction by a little bit. And the `\left...\right` option has the same height as the `\biggr` option, but it introduces a little extra space between the `+` and the fraction. I'm having trouble deciding between these options. Is there a best practice for typesetting this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122331/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/

Comment: @egreg I agree those are related, though I don't think either of them addresses best practices for this particular situation.

Comment: My suggestion would be to make it as a macro like `\EvalAt[\Big]{t=0} ` and then leave it to each case as to how much to scale. Left right constructions end up looking bad on most cases anyway

Comment: This looks like a task for __mathtools__’s `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `\big` is the minimum requested size anyway, it's better to use a simpler approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\evalat}{sO{\big}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\mleft. #3 \mright|_{#4}}
   {#3#2|_{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
& \evalat{f(x)}{x=0} \\
& \evalat[\big]{f(x)}{x=0} \\
& \evalat[\Big]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{x=0} \\
& \evalat[\bigg]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{x=0} \\
& \evalat*{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{x=0} \\
& \evalat[\bigg]{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}}{x=0} \\
& \evalat*{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}}{x=0} \\
& \evalat[\bigg]{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\!x^2}}{x=1} \\
& \evalat*{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\!x^2}}{x=1}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that the last one has a definitely too big bar.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Elaborating on daleif’s suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\evaluat{.}{\rvert}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\evaluat{nostar}{\mathopen{}#2\mathclose{#3}}

\begin{document}

Some examples:
\begin{itemize}
    \item with \verb|\evaluat[\big]|
        \[\evaluat[\big]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
    \item with \verb|\evaluat[\Bigg]|
        \[\evaluat[\Bigg]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
    \item with \verb|\evaluat*|
        \[\evaluat*{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
        (in this case, a \verb|\left|\ \ldots\verb|\right| construction is
        used);
    \item and with \verb|\evaluat| (thanks again, egreg~;-)
        \[\evaluat{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

---

### Afterthought

Since the OP put an emphasis on questions of style and best usage, I must 
correct an evident imperfection of the above code: although the `\evaluat` 
command produces, in all variants, a math list that begins with an 
Open atom and ends with a Close atom, nevertheless `\evaluat*` inserts 
`\nulldelimiterspace` on the left of the mandatory argument, while the 
other forms do not.  This is easily corrected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\evaluat{.}{\rvert}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\evaluat{nostar}{%
    \mathopen{}#2\mathclose{#3}%
}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\evaluat{star}{%
    \mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup #1\hskip -\nulldelimiterspace \relax
    #2\aftergroup\egroup #3%
}

\begin{document}

Some examples:
\begin{itemize}
    \item with \verb|\evaluat[\big]|
        \[\evaluat[\big]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
    \item with \verb|\evaluat[\Bigg]|
        \[\evaluat[\Bigg]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
    \item with \verb|\evaluat*|
        \[\evaluat*{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
        (in this case, a \verb|\left|\ \ldots\verb|\right| construction is
        used);
    \item and with \verb|\evaluat| (thanks again, egreg~;-)
        \[\evaluat{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}_{x=0}\]
\end{itemize}

Difference between non-\verb|\big| and \verb|\big|:
$\evaluat{x}$, $\evaluat[\big]{x}$.

Test for \verb|\nulldelimiterspace|:
\begin{align*}
    & 1+\evaluat{f(x)}_{x=0} \\
    & 1+\evaluat*{f(x)}_{x=0}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Output of the amended code]

Let us also magnify the portion pertaining to the `\nulldelimiterspace`
test:

[image: Detail of the previous image]

Of course, the rationale behind the choice of using
`\DeclarePairedDelimiter` was that a simple definition would suffice, with
the **mathtools** package taking care of all the details; if one needs to
have recourse so heavily to callback routines, I agree with egreg that this
approach loses its sense, and that it is better to directly define an
appropriate command, as he does (however, I would recommend the same
correction in his code too, and also to arrange for the generated math list
to always begin with an Open atom—albeit unlikely, an Op could precede).

Comment: Don't try `\evaluat` without the optional argument. `;-)`

Comment: A comment to myself: is really an initial Op atom the right thing to do?  Consider `\[\limsup_{n\to\infty} \evaluat[\bigg]{\frac{df}{dx}}_{x=1/n}\]`…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks for adding in the details to fix the `\nulldelimiterspace`. I didn't include any Open atoms in my first two examples, with `\Bigr` and `\biggr`; I guess I could have inserted some `\mathopen{}` atoms. But are you suggesting (in your comment to yourself) that such atoms are unnecessary?

Comment: @justin: Actually more than this: I am changing my mind once more, and I am beginning to think that an initial `\mathopen` is actually wrong.  Perhaps the best thing of all is to encompass the whole construction in an Ord atom…  I no longer know: now it’s bedtime for me, I’ll come back fresh tomorrow! :-)  __Edit:__ Good question, anyway!

Answer (score 9):

I've recently adopted [the `physics` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/physics) as part of my usual tool kit, with the advantage that it provides a tool explicitly for this `\evaluated{}` (or `\eval{}`).

It seems to apply a minimum size bar, and to scale it up as needed.

Here is an minimal example extracted from a document I wrote for class recently

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
here we recognize the terminal velocity in the denominator of the
RHS
\begin{align*}
  \Delta x 
  &= \mp\frac{m}{k} \int_{v_1}^{v_2}
    \frac{v\dd{v}}{v^2 \pm v_t^2}  \\
  \\
  &= \mp\frac{m}{k} \frac{1}{2} \eval{\ln\qty({v^2 \pm
    v_t^2})}_{v_1}^{v_2}  \\
  \\
  &= \mp\frac{m}{2k} 
    \qty[\ln\qty(v_2^2 \pm v_t^2) - \ln\qty(v_1^2 \pm v_t^2)]  \,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which generates this output:

[image]

The use of `\eval` is on the second line of the `align` environment.

Answer (score 2):

I propose another solution, base on `raisebox` and a `tabular` environment. It allows for a greater control on the height and depth of the bar. It is possible (I didn't do it) to have a `key=value` system to have the height of the bar as a factor times the height of its contents, and its depth as another factor times the depth of the contents.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\eval[1]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{\,}|@{\,}}% 
\raisebox{0pt}[0.85\height][1.33\depth]{$ \displaystyle#1 $}\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & 5 + \eval{\dfrac{df}{dt}}_{t = 0} \\[2ex]
    & 5 + \eval{\frac{d\Bigl(\dfrac{f}{g}\Bigr)}{dt}}_{t = 0}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The seems to be too much space before the condition `t=0`.

Comment: @Andrew Swann: Yes?  I wonder why I used `\enspace`. I guess I modified some older code and forgot to check this  spacing I've replaced it with something more sensible. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

While trying to adapt [Bernard’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294543/69818) to a similar question ([Vertical bar for “evaluated at”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376541/69818)), I noticed that it is defective in that it smashes the height of the “evaluated” subformula, as it can clearly be seen in this modified example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\eval[1]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{\,}|@{\,}}% 
\raisebox{0pt}[0.33\height][1.33\depth]{$ \displaystyle#1 $}\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & 5 + \eval{\dfrac{df}{dt}}_{t = 0} \\[2ex]
    & 5 + \eval{\frac{d\Bigl(\dfrac{f}{g}\Bigr)}{dt}}_{t = 0}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: Output of first code sample]

However, I liked the idea of using a vertical rule instead of a `\vert` delimiter, so I worked out another solution based on this same principle.  The height and the depth of the rule are computed keeping in mind the rules detailed in Appendix G of *The TeXbook* for the placement of subscripts (Rules 18a and 18b).  Of course, I’ve open to suggestions for what concerns the value of the various parameters.

Here is my current proposal:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath} % I always load it when dealing with math!

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\evaluateat[2]{%
    #1% first, typeset the base symbol(s)
    \mkern .5\thinmuskip % too little? too much?
    \mathpalette{\EA@evaluate@at{#2}}{#1}% then, add the vertical bar
}
\newcommand*\EA@evaluate@at[3]{%
    % #1 <- subscripted annotation
    % #2 <- style selector, e.g., "\textstyle"
    % #3 <- base symbol(s)
    \setbox\z@ \hbox{$\m@th\color@begingroup #2#3\color@endgroup$}%
    \dimen@ \dimexpr \ht\z@ *\tw@/\thr@@ \relax
    \dimen@ii \dp\z@
    \ifx #2\scriptscriptstyle
        \EA@calc@style@dependent@values \scriptscriptfont \scriptscriptfont
    \else \ifx #2\scriptstyle
        \EA@calc@style@dependent@values \scriptfont \scriptscriptfont
    \else
        \EA@calc@style@dependent@values \textfont \scriptfont
    \fi \fi
    \vrule \@height\dimen@ \@depth\dimen@ii \@width\dimen4
    \mathord{% or "\mathclose{}\mathopen{}\mathinner{"?
        \vrule \@depth\dp\z@ \@height\z@ \@width\z@
    }% } brace match
    _{\,#1}%
}
\newcommand*\EA@calc@style@dependent@values[2]{%
    % #1 <- main font selector, e.g., "\textfont"
    % #2 <- relative script font selector, e.g., "\scriptfont"
    \advance \dimen@ii \fontdimen19#2\tw@
    \dimen4 \fontdimen16#1\tw@
    \ifdim \dimen@ii<\dimen4
        \dimen@ii \dimen4
    \fi
    \advance \dimen@ii \dimen4 % extra depth
    % \dimen4 \dimexpr \fontdimen5#1\tw@ *6/5\relax
    \dimen4 \fontdimen5#1\tw@ % the ex-height
    \ifdim \dimen4 <\z@
        \dimen4 -\dimen4
    \fi
    \ifdim \dimen@<\dimen4
        \dimen@ \dimen4
    \fi
    % Now re-use "\dimen4" to hold the default rule thickness:
    \dimen4 \fontdimen8#1\thr@@
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In-line: \( \evaluateat{\mathord.}{x=0} + \evaluateat{f}{x=0} +
\evaluateat{f(x)}{x=0} + \evaluateat{\frac{df}{dx}}{x=0} \).  And displayed:
\[
    \evaluateat{f}{x=0}+\evaluateat{\frac{df}{dx}}{x=0}
        - \evaluateat{\,\frac{\frac{df}{dx}\,}{\,\frac{df}{dy}\,}}{x=0,y=0}
\]

Example in \verb|\scriptstyle|:
\( \frac{\evaluateat{f(x)}{x=0}}{g\left(\evaluateat{f(x)}{x=0}\right)} \).

Another example:
\[ \evaluateat{df}{x} \colon T_{x}M\longrightarrow T_{y}N \]

\end{document}
```

This is the output it yields:

[image: Output of the second code sample]