# How to put a vertical line with derivative

Tags: line-numbering

Dear All in attached image how I can put a vertical line with derivative .Any command for this please?

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter: Please don't downvote a question without leaving a comment explaining where the question needs improvement. Especially if it's the first question of a new community member.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also related: [“Evaluated at” bar for derivatives: \Bigr, \biggr, or \left…\right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294499/69818).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\rd{\mathrm d}
\begin{document}
\[
\left.\frac{\rd y}{\rd x}\right|_{x=0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try this code:  $\dfrac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{x=2}$