# Can you help how to write this?

Tags: math-mode

Please can you help me with this ,how can i write this one?[image]

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294499/evaluated-at-bar-for-derivatives-bigr-biggr-or-left-right help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Evaluated at" bar for derivatives: \Bigr, \biggr, or \left...\right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294499/evaluated-at-bar-for-derivatives-bigr-biggr-or-left-right)

Answer (score 4):

try the below code

```
$$\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=-1}=-5$$
```

Comment: [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/106162)

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: @Sevdije --- it should be \\[ ... \\], but getting backslashes to display properly in comments can be awkward.

Answer (score 3):

Your post has the vertical line extended well below the baseline. If this is important to you, try this code:

```
\[\frac{dy}{dx}\,{\rule[-3.5ex]{.1ex}{7.0ex}\,}_{x=-1}=-5\]
```

This allows you manual control of the vertical line. In the code above, the -3.5 controls the depth of the line, the .1 controls the thickness of the line and the 7.0 controls the total height of the line.