# `evaluate at` delimiters

Tags: scaling, delimiters, mathtools

I am using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` command from the `mathtools` package to declare some new delimiters, for which scaling can be turned on and off easily.
Specifically, I want to declare the command `\evalat`, which indicates the evaluation of an expression at a given point: e.g. `$\left.\frac{x}{2}\right|_{x=1}$`.

As I said before, I want it to have the scaling options as provided by the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`-type commands.
This means that `\evalat{\frac{x}{2}}{x=1}` gives a non-scaled vertical line on the right, `\evalat*{\frac{x}{2}}{x=1}` gives a scaled vertical line on the right and `\evalat[\size]{\frac{x}{2}}{x=1}` gives a vertical bar with size `\size`.

I tried the following definitions:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\evalat}[2]{}{.}{|}{_{#2}}{#1}
```

and

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\evalat}[2]{}{\left.}{\right|}{_{#2}}{#1}
```

The first one works correctly in the starred (automatic scaling) version. Its non-starred version however results in `$.\frac{x}{2}|_{x=1}$`, with the dot still shown on the left side.
The second version always scales the delimiters, both in the starred and the non-starred version.

I understand why the commands behave as they do, but I do not know how to get the behaviour that I want?

PS. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294517/165534) answer to another question could be a fall-back solution, but I would rather have the `_{x=1}` as an argument to the command.

Comment: As is the declarepaired cannot handle "empty" fences. I tend to make the Eval at macro completely manual as I find the `\EvalAt{expression}{point} ` cumbersome and unnatural to read. I tend to just have `expression `\EvalAt[scaler]{point}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simpler to define the command directly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\evalat}{sO{}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.#3\right|_{#4}}
    {#3#2|_{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\evalat{x^2}{x=1}=1
\qquad
\evalat*{\frac{x^2}{3}}{x=6}=12
\qquad
\evalat[\Big]{\frac{x^2}{3}}{x=6}=12
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]