# Vertical line, subscript x=a

Tags: math-mode

How do I write this formula in latex?
[image]

I tried this:

```
\big(f(x,b)\big)'_x|_{x=a}
```

[image]

but the result is different from what I want (the line is shorter).

I understand that this is probably a simple question but I can't find the answer probably because I can't find good words for the search

Comment: `\left.\bigl(f(x,b)\bigr)'_x\right|_{x=a}`?

Comment: @user241266 thanks! It's what I want

Comment: For a pretty exhaustive discussion, also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294499/158639 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in comments by [user241266](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/241266/user241266), the correct thing to do is

```
\left.\bigl(f(x,b)\bigr)'_x\right|_{x=a}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\bigl(f(x,b)\bigr)'_x\Big|_{x=a}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]