# Vertical bar for "evaluated at"

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subscripts, delimiters

I would like to create a vertical "evaluation" bar similar to the one in this formula:

[image]

This was produced by the code:

```
df\,_{\big\rvert x} \colon T_x M \to T_y N
```

It comes close to what I want, but I am not entirely satisfied: I would like the 'x' to be lower (e.g. aligned with the bottom of the vertical bar). Also maybe have the vertical bar slightly less tall.

Suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad5aK.png)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Evaluated at” bar for derivatives: \Bigr, \biggr, or \left…\right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294499/69818).

Comment: In particular, I’d suggest adapting [@Bernard’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294543/69818) to your iiking.

Comment: Related?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122331/derivatives-enter-evaluated-at-vertical-bar-with-multiple-values-as-subscript

Comment: @Werner: not bad, how did you make it?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti and Steven B. Segletes: I don't see a solution in your links, because I want my bar lower than what I see there.

Comment: @Seub: See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/sxnKduUW).

Comment: @Werner: thank you, that is good enough for me. AboAmmar's answer also works.

Comment: @Seub: I’ve posted [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376629/69818) to the [question I cited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294499/69818), which tries to address your needs.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: thank you, it looks great. For my needs, I'll stick to Mico's suggestion in the comments to AboAmmar's answer, namely: `\newcommand\evalat[1]{_{\mkern1.5mu\big\vert_{\scriptstyle #1}}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

> [image]

To get the vertical bar a bit larger, you can use `\raisebox`. This way, the `\vert` will be in the normal math size and `x` will be in the `\scriptsize` style. Alternatively, you can use `\mbox` if you don't like `\raisebox`. In this case, the usual font sizes can be used (tiny, scriptsize, footnotesize, small, normalsize, large, Large, LARGE, huge, Huge).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx}
\begin{document}

\[
  df\,\raisebox{-.5em}{$\vert_{x}$} \colon T_x M \to T_y N
\]
%
\[
  df\,_{\mbox{$\vert_{x}$}} \colon T_x M \to T_y N
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. For my own taste, I inserted a \big before the \vert.

Comment: +1. Two suggestions. First, consider moving the `\,` directive inside the argument of `\raisebox` or `\mbox`. Second, `\,` may provide to much whitespace; consider inserting half as much whitespace by issuing the directive `\mkern1.5mu` instead.

Comment: @Mico: Perfect, thank you! So, for those interested, I did: `\newcommand{\evalat}[1]{_{\mbox{${\mkern1.5mu}\big\vert_{#1}$}}}`

Comment: @Seub - You may also want to give `\newcommand\evalat[1]{_{\mkern1.5mu\big\vert_{\scriptstyle #1}}}` a try.

Comment: @Mico Yep, I'm keeping your suggestion!