# Condition/consideration on Equation

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

How can one reproduce the vertical line with the consideration of B=20kHz in the following equation?

[image: condition]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122331/derivatives-enter-evaluated-at-vertical-bar-with-multiple-values-as-subscript and the linked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[
\textrm{SNDR} = \left.\frac{P_{\rm signal}}{P_{\rm noise} + P_{\rm distortion}}\right|_{B = 20\,{\rm kHz}} \,(\textrm{dB})
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes look also my profile and question on Math/Physics.SE. My best regards.