# A Symbol in Taylor's formula?

Tags: symbols, polynom

does anyone know how to make the vertical line (before subscript op) for Taylor's polynomial?
Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122332/218142

Comment: Welcome! If you show us a complete, minimal working example (MWE) showing what you've done thus far, we can better help you.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! I didn't what the symbol is called.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is my code
\begin{equation}
    \hat{h}_i(x,y) = h_{i,op}  + \left. \frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x} \right|_{op} (x - x_{op}) + \left. \frac{\partial h_i}{\partial y} \right|_{op} (y - y_{op}),
\end{equation}

Comment: @TPS Your image can be realized in many differents mode. I have chosen `diffcoeff` package.

   `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{diffcoeff}
    \diffdef{pvrule}{op-symbol=\partial}
    \begin{document}
     \[\hat{h}_i(x,y)= \hat{h}_{i,\text{op}}+\diff.pvrule.{h_i}x[\text{op}](x-x_{\text{op}})+\diff.pvrule.{h_i}y[\text{op}](y-y_{\text{op}})\]
    \end{document}`